# Tomcat deploys but doesn't serve

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to start up tomcat server, but I can't reach web page.

Here are my logs:

```
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1522 ms
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Mar 22, 2015 7:15:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
```

Could you give me a path to fix the problem?

Comment: depends quite much the content of ROOT directory

Comment: did you use the right port? I ROOT still holding your default tomcat welcome page? According to the log there is no other webapp deployed

Comment: How are you trying to access your web page ? What is the URL you're using ?

Comment: I try to access like : ip:8080 I try to remove tomcat and reinstall  by sudo apt-get remove and sudo-apt get install or even I tried to purge tomcat but nothing works. There looks no problem but I can't reach the server. Root is main app that comes with tomcat to show you if it is working fine.

Comment: If you're running tomcat on your local machine, then you can try `localhost:8080` to see tomcat's page, you don't have to use your ip

Comment: does not seem the deployment is completed... tomcat should write further lines, such as:
`
Mar 22, 2015 2:12:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2293 ms
~

Comment: @Sanny yes I read logs and never say Server startup what can be  the issue ?  After INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml there is nothing happens and I also tried to find the file 'host-manager.xml' but I couldn't find it at that place.

Comment: check in logs directory catalina.out to see if there's any exception

Comment: No there is no problem just hangs at the last line which is
    /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml

Comment: See if this helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/655616/tomcat7-hangs-on-deploying-apps